# Plot error bars for each point in multi-line graph

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'y': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 't': ['t1', 't1', 't1', 't2', 't2', 't2']}, index=[1, 5, 10, 1, 5, 10])
ax = df.groupby('t')['y'].plot(legend=False)

plt.show()
```

which produces the following graph:
[image]

That is, a multiple line graph with 3 x-axis points (1, 5, 10) each line. I would like to add error bars on each line on each of the 3 x-axis points, that is yerr bars.

In the past, with a single line, I created a list like this one:

```
yerr = [ [], [] ]
```

Where the first sublist is the lower-bound of the error bars and the second sublist the upper-bound of the error bars for each point on the x-axis.

I tried to do something like this here, but it complains that it's expecting 3 values instead of 6. How would I construct the yerr so I can then supply it to the plotting like so:

```
ax = df.groupby('t')['y'].plot(yerr=yerr)
```

Thank you!

Comment: In this OP, there is only 1 value per point per group, so there is no error. `sns.pointplot(data=df, x=df.index, y='y', hue='t', ci='sd', dodge=0.25)`.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney thank for your comment, It's as a proof of concept to draw the graph, assuming that each point does have an error, how should I construct the yerr list so that the error can be plotted?

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney the duplicate question you are posting is not using custom error bars. I am calculating the 95% CI for each point for each line and I need to display that error.

Comment: That's being redundant. [`seaborn.pointplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pointplot.html) does the 95% ci by default. Change it to `ci=95`.

Comment: WOW! seaborn seems much nicer than Pandas plotting capabilities!!! Thank you very much!!!!!!

Comment: Just depends on what you're trying to do. `seaborn` is just a high-level api for `matplotlib`. By default, `pandas` uses `matplotlib` as the backend. Should I close this question as a duplicate?

Comment: Yes, please! Thank you very much. Will have seaborn in mind